# Implicit vs explicit conversions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, casting, warnings, ctype, directcast

I have a project written in VB.NET that is part of a larger solution. My knowledge of VB.NET is extremely limited. This project generates hundreds of warnings concerning implicit conversions during a build.

Example: `Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'Integer'`:

[image]

Here, it complains that `GetKey` returns an `Object` and that's implicitly converted to `Integer`.

So I've added either a `CType` or a `DirectCast`.

[image]

Now, it says that the cast is redundant and I should remove it.

I'm confused. What should I do? I'd like to get rid of the compiler warnings.

Comment: Have you set `Option Strict On` or `Off`? It is `Off` by default and I'm guessing that you haven't turned it `On`. You should absolutely do that. Do it in the project properties and also do it in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default in all new projects. If you want to, you can turn it `On` at the file level for one file at a time, allowing you successfully build along the way. With `Option Strict On`, implicit narrowing conversions are not allowed, so I would expect that second message to go away.

Comment: Note that neither of these messages is telling you that your code is wrong. The first is letting you know that you're providing an `Object` reference where an `Integer` is expected so you ought to confirm that the value provided will definitely be an `Integer`. Notice the first message isn't telling you to cast. It's just telling you that an implicit conversion is occurring.

Comment: By the way, VB provides some shortcut operators for `CType` with native data types. To make code more succinct, I tend to use `CStr`, `CInt`, etc, rather than `DirectCast` for a native data type. What you do is up to you.

Comment: `Option strict` was not enabled. Now I get errors instead of those warnings so I definitely have to fix them.